# Does IDBIndex.getAll() return a sorted list?

Tags: javascript, indexeddb

I'm looking into the [`IDBIndex.getAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IDBIndex/getAll) method of the IndexedDB API. However, it's not clear from the documentation if the result of the call to this method should be a sorted or unsorted list of indexed entries.

Also, all the examples of using an ordered results are using the cursor manually to retrieve the entries, is this the only way to make an ordered query?

Answer (score 2):

I see the following info in the spec:

> https://www.w3.org/TR/IndexedDB/#object-store-construct An object store has a list of records which hold the data stored in the object store. Each record consists of a key and a value. **The list is sorted according to key in ascending order**. There can never be multiple records in a given object store with the same key.
>
> https://www.w3.org/TR/IndexedDB/#index-construct **The records in an index are always sorted according to the record's key**. However unlike object stores, a given index can contain multiple records with the same key. Such records are additionally sorted according to the index's record's value (meaning the key of the record in the referenced object store).
>
> https://www.w3.org/TR/IndexedDB/#cursor-construct **For cursors iterating indexes the situation is a little bit more complicated** since multiple records can have the same key and are therefore also sorted by value. When iterating indexes the cursor also has an object store position, which indicates the value of the previously found record in the index. Both position and the object store position are used when finding the next appropriate record.
>
> https://www.w3.org/TR/IndexedDB/#cursor-iteration-operation **records is always sorted in ascending key order**. In the case of source being an index, records is secondarily sorted in ascending value order (where the value in an index is the key of the record in the referenced object store).
>
> https://www.w3.org/TR/IndexedDB/#object-store-retrieval-operation To retrieve multiple values from an object store with targetRealm, store, range and optional count, run these steps: ... Let records be **a list containing the first count records in store’s list** of records whose key is in range.

My guess is that internally `getAll` is a trivial utility decorator of `openCursor` such that we can infer it follows the same ordering criteria.

> https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/66.0.3359.158/third_party/WebKit/Source/modules/indexeddb/docs/idb_overview.md
> All IDB queries are scoped to a single object store (i.e., no equivalent of SQL joins). IDB supports single-key CRUD (get, put, delete). IDB also supports range-based retrieval (get, getAll) and iteration (like cursors used by many RDBMS implementations). **Iteration follows the implicit ordering of the source (object store or index), but can either go in the forward direction / ascending order, or in the backward direction / descending order**.

Comment: Thank you Josh for pointing to the relevant bits of the specification. Sadly, the semantics of the retrieval methods is not explicitly specified, so the must be some degree of assumptions. Probably the source code of the Chromium would be the best source of truth for this matter :)

Answer (score 0):

[Here is where the spec talks about how IDBIndex.getAll gets its data:](https://www.w3.org/TR/IndexedDB/#dom-idbindex-getall)

> 6. Let operation be an algorithm to run [retrieve multiple referenced values from an index](https://www.w3.org/TR/IndexedDB/#retrieve-multiple-referenced-values-from-an-index) with the current Realm, index, range, and count if given.

Follow that link and it says:

> 2. Let records be a list containing the first count records in index’s [list of records](https://www.w3.org/TR/IndexedDB/#index-list-of-records) whose key is in range.

and then says it takes records in order from that list. Again following the link, you get the definition of an index's list of records, which includes this:

> The records in an index are always sorted according to the record's key. However unlike object stores, a given index can contain multiple records with the same key. Such records are additionally sorted according to the index's record's value (meaning the key of the record in the referenced object store).

So that's how the data returned by IDBIndex.getAll is sorted.